# FIRMA PKCS#1 RSA Sha256WithRsa

Tags: java, cifrado

Necesito firmar una cadena para enviar a una entidad financiera por medio de un `WebService`.

Los pasos son los siguientes:

**Procedimiento para generar el valor del parámetro firma**

1. Generar la cadena original del mensaje de consulta o del mensaje de salida, según sea el caso.
2. Aplicar a la cadena original del mensaje de consulta o del mensaje de salida, según sea el caso, el procedimiento de esquema de firma descrito en la *sección 8.2 RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5* del documento *RFC 3447 Public-Key Cryptography Standards (PKCS) #1: RSA Cryptography Specifications Version 2.1.*
3. Aplicar al resultado del procedimiento anterior un filtrado en base 64, como se describe en el documento *RFC 4648 The Base16, Base32, and Base64 Data Encodings.*
4. Asentar el resultado del *inciso 3* en el parámetro “firma”, para incorporarlo como parte de los parámetros de consulta en la solicitud correspondiente.

**Ejemplo del documento guía**

a. Se genera la siguiente cadena original del mensaje de consulta

```
|14/12/2016 18:01:08|operador0125|ABCD1234567F8|fisica|
```

b. A la cadena original del mensaje de consulta se le aplica los pasos 2 y 3 del proceso de firma descrito en la sección 3, del cual se obtiene la siguiente cadena:

```
Htu1kKxYUPLKSDDYZ0g2lR0qH5grAOwuW3RRyCTXuJU68jD170hCmNg8m7SGgrIWh07YkRlnhcZs6zwwiHpPSCQtVKLgkMsZ0Q0ENZ9h2/M88ZiNDTrUQft/WGlNsvNKNbb5oOZQ4lM/mCvTl3Zdy7A40kpS54QqMUIEdyWkVpibriHAsuWv8KZHQBvSYm2rZ0rJBEuGs7I2IMWxgCy9yHh7ub7dyqmzWmtQL87HC7yEPgLPnNFXyj53ylS2Pv/B0tgdHfmvx3lyZ2BDJdN0ImW2JXwMlNOhzLvQF80JsJSIeNH+m5JUrjA2Ntfb3/m71obg9tfAuwU7NsPZoSJ2pg==
```

---

1. Me dan un archivo .cer:

   ```
   00000100000100012095.cer
   ```
2. Un .cve que contiene:

   ```
   -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
   Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
   DEK-Info: AES-128-CBC,041BEED517ABF2499A0A70247B392DC3

   RA3VnZHkktMcBpCa7u0+j1l56CRoKezQwMWdrU0Nevj3y0Ff+VFsuFKPDyoTmN45
   60okZEazBwI+jPF3sLbHvuQMPE2pUTrU0Y1x6cjnTMqg9FKxo/o3Za64KjIkbGde
   ............................................... más contenido...
   -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
   ```
3. Una frase de seguridad de 14 caracteres:

   ```
   123_XXXXXXXXXX
   ```

Lo que he investigado, para generar una firma (`PKCS`) #1, con `Sha256WithRSA`, y al final Se debe pasar a `Base64`, de todos los archivos, sólo necesito el `.cer`, que es dónde obtengo la llave pública, y sólo debo cifrar la cadena original, es correcto, pero cada vez que ejecuto el código me genera un resultado diferente. Eso es normal?

**Mi código** es el siguiente:

```
byte[] encodedBytes;


String encodedBytesStr;
System.out.println("firmaCompuesta: " + firmaCompuesta);
try {
    boolean useBouncyCastleProvider = true;

    Provider provider = null;
    if (useBouncyCastleProvider) {
        provider = new BouncyCastleProvider();
        Security.addProvider(provider);
    }

    // Message Digest
    Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());

    FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(FILENAME_CER);
    CertificateFactory f = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
    X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate) f.generateCertificate(fin);
    PublicKey publickey = certificate.getPublicKey();

    String hashingAlgorithm = "SHA-256";

    MessageDigest messageDigestProvider = null;
    if (null != provider) {
        messageDigestProvider = MessageDigest.getInstance(hashingAlgorithm, provider);
    } else {
        messageDigestProvider = MessageDigest.getInstance(hashingAlgorithm);
    }
    messageDigestProvider.update(firmaCompuesta.getBytes());

    byte[] hash = messageDigestProvider.digest();

    DigestAlgorithmIdentifierFinder hashAlgorithmFinder = new DefaultDigestAlgorithmIdentifierFinder();
    AlgorithmIdentifier hashingAlgorithmIdentifier = hashAlgorithmFinder.find(hashingAlgorithm);

    DigestInfo digestInfo = new DigestInfo(hashingAlgorithmIdentifier, hash);
    byte[] hashToEncrypt = digestInfo.getEncoded();

    // Crypto
    // You could also use "RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding" for both the BC and SUN Providers.
    Cipher encCipher = null;
    if (null != provider) {
        encCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/NONE/PKCS1Padding", provider);
    } else {
        encCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
    }

    //=============== JEMJ CIFRADO DESDE .CER =============
    encCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publickey);

    byte[] encrypted = encCipher.doFinal(hashToEncrypt);

    System.out.println("\n\nHash and Encryption Output : \n\n");
    //
    encodedBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(encrypted);
    encodedBytesStr = new String(encodedBytes);
    //
    System.out.println(encodedBytesStr);
```

Comment: No, para firmar siempre se necesita la llave privada con su respectivo password, en ese proceso no deberá influir la llave pública, por el algoritmo creo que debería darte siempre la misma firma si son los mismos datos

Comment: tengo que crear el mismo servicio, me ayudarias?, please, saludos

Comment: @Carlos por favor completa el [tour] y lee [ask] y [answer]. Las respuestas no deben usarse para realizar nuevas preguntas.

Comment: que onda amigo como vas? yo tambien estoy generando el mismo prosedimiento.